# Open existing Node.js Project in a TypeScript project

Tags: node.js, typescript

I currently have an existing project in Node.js and I would like to migrate it to a TypeScript project.

How can I do this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to look at the Node sample provided with the TypeScript. It already includes declarations for the built-in NodeJS modules.

After importing the node.js you can start by converting your modules one by one. Since the Typescript will convert into JS, you can convert one file at a time and test it right away!

With [ambients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771258/how-to-import-javascript-modules-in-typescript) it should be easy to do! Good luck with your conversion.