# Comparing knockout.js and TypeScript

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I have a Windows form program (think something like Paint.NET) that I want to port into a web client side applicaton.

I have started playing with knockout.js and it seems it might (not totally sure though) be able to do the work.  Then I hear about TypeScript.  From the descrption, it says it is for "application scale Javascript development".  I don't have the resources to invest in evaluating both.

Is knockout.js or TypeScript a better choice?  Or are they not comparable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

TypeScript is a language which compiles to javascript, Knockout is a MVVM javasript library to help you organize your client side code. They can work together.

Comment: +1 you can write your program in TypeScript and use Knockout, Backbone, jQuery, Angular or any other JavaScript library or framework.

Comment: more information about how to combine them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689716/typescript-with-knockoutjs). Typescript provides static typing which is always nice when learning a new library/framework. You don't need much time to start with it, you can get an idea on their [website](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/)